# How to take log2 of scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This code I run errs at `np.log2()`. It will work if I give it `tmp.data` as input as opposed to `tmp`. Which leads me to conclude `np.log2()` does not work on `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` but can on `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` converted to `ndarray` through calling `csr_matrix.data`.

The only problem is, the code below what I can change expects to get a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix`. What do I do?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm
import scipy
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, diags
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: {} output_filename".format(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

# here are a few helper functions you might find useful...
def multiply_by_rows(matrix, coefficients):
    diag = diags(coefficients, 0)
    return diag * matrix

def multiply_by_columns(matrix, coefficients):
    diag = diags(coefficients, 0)
    return matrix * diag

print("Loading cooccurrence matrix...")
with np.load("cooccur.npz") as loader:
    PPMI = csr_matrix((loader['data'], loader['indices'],
        loader['indptr']), shape=loader['shape'])

print("Computing PPMI...")
print(type(PPMI))

##### FILL IN THE CODE HERE #####
# you should compute the PMI matrix and save it into the PPMI variable.
# Hint: the following functions/attributes might be useful:
#
# - csr_matrix.sum()
# - csr_matrix.data
# - array.sum()
# - np.reciprocal()
# - np.log2()
# - multiply_by_rows() (above)
# - multiply_by_columns() (above)

# Refer to page 16 of chapter word embeddings
sum_of_all_values = csr_matrix.sum(PPMI)
sum_of_all_cols   = csr_matrix.sum(PPMI,axis=0)
sum_of_all_rows   = csr_matrix.sum(PPMI,axis=1) 
print(type(sum_of_all_values))

joint_probabilities = PPMI / sum_of_all_values
joint_probabilities_cols = sum_of_all_cols / sum_of_all_values
joint_probabilities_rows = sum_of_all_rows / sum_of_all_values
print(type(joint_probabilities))

tmp = multiply_by_rows(joint_probabilities, np.reciprocal(np.squeeze(np.asarray(joint_probabilities_cols))))
tmp = multiply_by_columns(tmp , np.reciprocal(np.squeeze(np.asarray(joint_probabilities_rows))))

print(type(tmp))

PPMI = np.log2(tmp)
print(type(PPMI))
##### STOP FILLING IN THE CODE HERE

# At this point, PPMI is actually PMI, so let's drop all negative values,
# sparsify, and then compute rank-50 SVD

#PPMI = max(0, PPMI)
PPMI.data[PPMI.data < 0] = 0
# sparisfy
PPMI.eliminate_zeros()

print("Computing SVD...")
u, s, vt = svds(PPMI, k = 50)

p = 1
emb = u * (s ** p)

# normalize embeddings to unit length so cos(x, y) == x.T * y
emb = (emb.T / norm(emb, axis=1, ord=2)).T

print("Saving embeddings...")
np.save(sys.argv[1], emb)
print("Done!")
```

Output and Error

```
Loading cooccurrence matrix...
Computing PPMI...
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'numpy.float32'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-f37e357d0d51> in <module>()
     44 #tmp3 = np.dot(tmp3, IC)
     45 
---> 46 PPMI = np.log2(tmp)
     47 print(type(PPMI))
     48 ##### STOP FILLING IN THE CODE HERE

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __getattr__(self, attr)
    684             return self.getnnz()
    685         else:
--> 686             raise AttributeError(attr + " not found")
    687 
    688     def transpose(self, axes=None, copy=False):

AttributeError: log2 not found
```

Comment: whay cant you convert the output of `np.log2(tmp.data)` back to a sparse matrix?

Comment: Applying a `log` to a sparse matrix doesn't really make sense because of all the implicit zeros which would evaluate to `-inf` leaving you with a non sparse non finite matrix. Unless you are ultimately computing something like `x log x` which leaves zero at zero.

Comment: @PaulPanzer I don't think that is an issue here. They are sparse but PPMI takes care of it.

Comment: @DrBwts that was the answer. I was trying csr_matrix.tocsr(PPMI). I only had to do csr_matrix(PPMI).
Thank you. Someone can close this thread now.

Comment: `csr` has a `log1p` method (which probably applies `np.log1p` directly to the `data` attribute).

Comment: @hpaulj that would take the natural log. I later remembered we could use the Change-of-Base formula to fix that. I've edited my answer for others. Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```
with np.load("cooccur.npz") as loader:
    PPMI = csr_matrix((PPMI, loader['indices'],
        loader['indptr']), shape=loader['shape'])
```

Using only csr_matrix(PPMI) will give shape problems for SVD

**Another approach** is to use the Change-of-Base formula. csr_matrix.log1p is said to take the natural logarithm which I did not need. Basic math manipulation would give us csr_matrix.log1p(PPMI) / csr_matrix.log1p(2) to be equivalent to np.log2(PPMI)